# C# - Read & Preview Font

Tags: c#, fonts

Can I read and preview fonts (mainly ttf and otf) in C#? What other languages can/should I use?

Read:

- Info like font family, font name

Preview:

- Use the font to display some text
- Any way to display all supported font characters?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Caution**: don't use System.Drawing / System.Windows.Forms if you want to preview OTF fonts. Unless they're TTF's in disguise, you won't get them to show. System.Drawing, based on GDI+, only supports TTF fonts!

However, if you can use .NET 3.0, you could use

```
Fonts.GetFontFamilies(location)
```

from **System.Windows.Media** namespace (just reference PresentationCore.dll).

From a **FontFamily**, you can get the individual **Typeface**s (.ttc files contain more than one 'font', but a **FontFamily** also combines the various weights and variants). And from a **Typeface**, you can call **TryGetGlyphTypeface** to get the **GlyphTypeface**, which has a **CharacterToGlyphMap** property, which should tell you which unicode codepoints are physically supported.

It also seems possible to use **GlyphTypeface** directly, but I see no way that you can handle .ttc files. However, if that's not relevant, just create a GlyphTypeface per file.

I'd advice against trying all Unicode codepoints sequentially though.

Comment: thanks. i'll look into it. its more of a personal project, so i can use whatever framework there is. i prefer the latest

Comment: did u mean ttf when u say ttc?

Comment: Nope, .ttc files are so-called TrueType Collection files. They contain several typefaces in one file. For instance Cambria.ttc, which contains Cambria Regular and Cambria Regular Math.

Comment: oh, fonts shld use that... having separate ttf files seem to just increase the number of fonts i see. i think having even 20 typefaces in 1 file shldnt increase the file size or speed too much ... just my 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

To preview a font you can render it out to a form like this:

```
public partial class MyForm: Form
{
   .
   .
   .
   public void ShowMyFont()
   {
      Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
      graphics.DrawString("Hello world!", new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: I believe original poster meant previewing not installed fonts - ie. from file.