# What are these numbers (ASCII or ?)?

Tags: c#, fonts, typeface, glyph

After reading an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439551/get-supported-characters-of-a-font-in-c-sharp) about fonts, i tried the code and i am getting same results as show in the article but i can't figure out what those numbers XXX:XXX represent. Are they ascii values or what?  What link should i read to understand about Typeface, GlyphTypeface mentioned in the answer?

Comment: You quote an article and dont bother reading it and looking it up in the documentation regarding the code sample? Must be a new professional attitude.

Comment: I read it that why tried running its code but couldn't understand its outcome. as simple as that. looks like not reading people question carefully is the new professional attitude..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well - those numbers xxx:xxx is actual a pair - left number indicates unicode code point (i.e. unicode character code) and right side indicates the index to the glyph in the font file.

AFAIK, in very simple terms, glyph is a character representation i.e. how a character would look in a particular font/type-face. You may have a same glyph used for multiple characters and hence index in glyph tables is used. Typography is a involved subject and you can find a lot of material online - search for it. Here are few wikipedia pages that may get you started:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph (see typography entry)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface

MSDN also has a lot of documentation (e..g http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface.aspx) but you need to get some basic background before that.