# Is is possible to determine the character set of a Font?

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding

I am printing the name of every font installed using the font, except when that font would render the name unreadable (i.e. symbols), where I use the default font (Segoe UI).

Now, I'm trying the following and found something that I can't understand:

```
var installedFonts = new System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection().Families;

foreach (var family in installedFonts)
{
    var font = new Font(family, 12);
    if (font.GdiCharSet == 2) // Symbols font
    {
        // Print using default font
    }
    else // Readable font
    {
        // Print using font
    }
}
```

It never prints using the default font. Furthermore, every font's [`GdiCharSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.gdicharset(v=vs.110).aspx) returns `1`, even when the font is using a different character set. Reading a bit more thoroughly, it says:

> This property returns 1, unless a different character set is specified in the [`Font(String, Single, FontStyle, GraphicsUnit, Byte)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7c7wc9z(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor.

So, apparently I am not creating the font correctly, because I don't specify a `Byte` value (I'm using a different constructor altogether). This makes me think there is another way (the "actual" way) to know the `CharSet` value of a font. But I can't find it anywhere. Does anyone know how I can find out this?

---

As a side note, Notepad manages to do it. Format > Font... opens the font selector. You can see that it displays the character set used under Script.

[image]

Comment: If you use ["Character Map"](http://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/wp-content/uploads/sites/4419/2015/07/CharMapWin7.png) windows tool, then you will notice what all fonts have an option to create any character set. So your question doesn't make sense. Your aim though seems like an attempt to determine "which characters can this font print" and that's another question, see e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439551/get-supported-characters-of-a-font-in-c-sharp) (for wpf).

Comment: @Sinatr I'm probably using the wrong approach, but it clearly is possible to identify somehow, since Notepad is doing it. My question is, how could this be done (since it is possible)? How can I know what `Byte` value to use in the mentioned constructor?

Comment: All byte values will generate font succesfully (try it, perhaps I am wrong). Will it contain needed characters - is a question.

Comment: Winforms [`FontDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.fontdialog.allowscriptchange(v=vs.110).aspx) uses another term - *script*.

Comment: @Sinatr No, you're right. Any value will generate the font correctly. But that's the value I want to know, I can't just make it up, it needs to be intrinsic to the font. Otherwise, the check I do on the next line becomes pointless.

Comment: It should be possible to use winapi to get such info. Start from [TEXTMETRIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145132(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @Sinatr Thanks, Sinatr. That was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `GetTextMetrics` function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144941(v=vs.85).aspx). When called using interop, it retrieves the following structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
internal struct TEXTMETRIC
{
   public int tmHeight;
   public int tmAscent;
   public int tmDescent;
   public int tmInternalLeading;
   public int tmExternalLeading;
   public int tmAveCharWidth;
   public int tmMaxCharWidth;
   public int tmWeight;
   public int tmOverhang;
   public int tmDigitizedAspectX;
   public int tmDigitizedAspectY;
   public char tmFirstChar;
   public char tmLastChar;
   public char tmDefaultChar;
   public char tmBreakChar;
   public byte tmItalic;
   public byte tmUnderlined;
   public byte tmStruckOut;
   public byte tmPitchAndFamily;
   public byte tmCharSet;
}
```

The last member of the struct, `tmCharSet`, is what you are looking for:

> The character set of the font. The character set can be one of the
>   following values: ANSI_CHARSET BALTIC_CHARSET CHINESEBIG5_CHARSET
>   DEFAULT_CHARSET EASTEUROPE_CHARSET GB2312_CHARSET GREEK_CHARSET
>   HANGUL_CHARSET MAC_CHARSET OEM_CHARSET RUSSIAN_CHARSET
>   SHIFTJIS_CHARSET SYMBOL_CHARSET TURKISH_CHARSET VIETNAMESE_CHARSET ...

Following [this link](https://www.cyotek.com/blog/retrieving-font-and-text-metrics-using-csharp), you can find a simple implementation of the necessary code.

Comment: Yeah, I was doing that, @Sinatr mentioned it. I'll accept as soon as I'm done. Thanks =]

Comment: If you need more support for this, feel free to ask in comment.