# ASP.NET C# GetFontFamilies on web

Tags: c#, asp.net, fonts, web

I want to get all supported characters of a font, that font is stored in `localhost:53625/fonts/WINGDNG2.TTF`. I has try this thread in Stackoverflow

> [Get supported characters of a font - in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439551/get-supported-characters-of-a-font-in-c-sharp)

but have no luck.
When

> Fonts.GetFontFamilies(@"C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\Arial.TTF");

return a list contain 1 family,

> Fonts.GetFontFamilies(new
>   Uri(http://localhost:53625/fonts/WINGDNG2.TTF));

return a list contain 0 family.

 Thank you for reading my question.

p/s: My project is a website using ASP.NET MVC5, so the function can be in C# (server side) or in Javascript (client site). If there are any codes can give me a list of supported characters of a font (with specific path like above), which side is no problem.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/MS/Internal/FontCache/FontCacheUtil.cs,648

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to access the file in way: "file://my_host/.../WINDING2.TTF". This is the only way?

Comment: Yes; you need to download the file.

Comment: If your font is on the same server, you can access it locally anyway.

Comment: Thank you. By using `Fonts.GetFontFamilies(Server.MapPath("~/fonts/") + fontName)` solved my problem!. p/s: fonts is stored in `/fonts/` in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of enumerating the Font Families, you can instantiate GlyphTypeface directly, if you know the font file location:

```
GlyphTypeface glyphTypeface = new GlyphTypeface(new Uri("file:///C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts\\Kooten.ttf"));
```

Then access the GlyphCharacterMap to get all the supported characters:

```
IDictionary<int, ushort> characterMap = glyph.CharacterToGlyphMap;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you **drone6505**. This is enough for **utf-16**, but how about **utf-32**? e.g. _Segoe UI Symbol_.