# How ti disable fallback font in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, fallback

How to disable fallback font in WPF?

I want to display text in a font that doesn't support all characters, but VS keeps replacing missing characters with fallback values.

Example, if I want to display "test" in a font that doesn't have code points for 'e' and 's',
I want to show only "tt" **not** "tESt" where 'E' and 'S' are in some other, fallback, font. Which is what is happening right now.

I've tried:

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding SampleText}" FontFamily="{Binding FFamily, FallbackValue={x:Null}}"/>`

but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: From [BindingBase.FallbackValue Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Data_BindingBase_FallbackValue)

> Gets or sets the value to use when the binding is unable to return a value.

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding SampleText}" FontFamily="{Binding FFamily, FallbackValue={x:Null}}"/>` Means that if binding of the property `FontFamily` fails then use the value of FallbackValue.

Comment: [wpf-globalization-and-localization-overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/wpf-globalization-and-localization-overview)  ||  [system.windows.media.fontfamily](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.fontfamily)

Comment: @Cfun: I already read everything about fonts and I know how fallback works. I just don't know how to turn it off.

Comment: Why do you need to provide value for the `TextBlock` containing not supported characters? BTW you may filter unsupported characters out using `IValueConverter`. Disabled fallback will cause `t□□t`.

Comment: You can make `IValueConverter` based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439551/get-supported-characters-of-a-font-in-c-sharp) solution.

Comment: @aepot: The idea is to show "Sample Text" in all available fonts. Therefore, it would be incorrect displaying characters (glyphs) which that font doesn't support. Showing t□□t would do the job. User could see which characters are not supported.
I could filter unsupported characters in `IValueConverter` but I'm afraid that it would be very time counsuming if you have hundrets or thousands of fonts. Disabling fallback is the cleanest way I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Wpf has a default fallback font.

You may replace this with one of your own.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.fontfamily?view=netcore-3.1

If you use a zero width ttf then i think that would give the result you're looking for.

In that each glyph is deliberately zero width.

I don't have a font missing glyphs to try this with, but it looks like it'd work.

https://github.com/patrickkunka/zero-width/blob/master/README.md