# How to extract set unicodes from an iconfont and display them in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I want to create a generic icon picker application. You select an iconfont and the application renders all available icons and you can copy their unicode selecting an icon.

I found this post [Get supported characters of a font - in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439551/get-supported-characters-of-a-font-in-c-sharp) and I thought that's exactly what I need and implemented it. I've put the found unicodes in an ObservableCollection and rendered the collection as an ItemsControl. This kinda works actually, but the displayed glyphs are no icons, rather than usual letters.

My guess is, that I messed up the conversion from the found characters to my unicode characters in the ObservableCollection?

```
var families = Fonts.GetFontFamilies(openFileDialog.FileName);
foreach (FontFamily family in families)
{
    var typefaces = family.GetTypefaces();
    foreach (Typeface typeface in typefaces)
    {
        GlyphTypeface glyph;
        typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out glyph);
        IDictionary<int, ushort> characterMap = glyph.CharacterToGlyphMap;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, ushort> kvp in characterMap)
        {
            //var iconChar = (char)kvp.Value;
            //Solution, changed to key instead of value
            var iconChar = (char)kvp.Key;

            // This is my OberservableCollection<char>
            this.FontCharacters.Add(iconChar);
        }
    }
}
```

And I render this like this:

```
<ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FontCharacters}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource IconButtonStyle}" FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/ProjectName;component/Fonts/#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid"></Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

#Update: I solved the issue, I just had to use they kvp.Key instead of the value and the correct icons are getting displayed now.

Comment: If you solved your own problem you should put the solution in the Your Answer box below. After a day or so you can accept your own answer, and your question will be marked as answered in the UI.

Comment: @DourHighArch Yeah that wasn't possible, therefore the update, but thanks for the reminder, I'll do that now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem with above code was, that kvp.Value was uses instead of kvp.Key.

Working Code:

```
var families = Fonts.GetFontFamilies(openFileDialog.FileName);
foreach (FontFamily family in families)
{
    var typefaces = family.GetTypefaces();
    foreach (Typeface typeface in typefaces)
    {
        GlyphTypeface glyph;
        typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out glyph);
        IDictionary<int, ushort> characterMap = glyph.CharacterToGlyphMap;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, ushort> kvp in characterMap)
        {
            //Solution, changed to key instead of value
            var iconChar = (char)kvp.Key;

            // This is my OberservableCollection<char>
            this.FontCharacters.Add(iconChar);
        }
    }
}
```