# How to make ClickOnce applications aware of new fonts?

Tags: fonts, devexpress, clickonce

To preface, I am required to use:
 * ClickOnce deployment
 * A barcode font
 * A DevExpress control that uses "FontName" with no access to the Font object, preventing me from using PrivateFontCollection.
 * The fonts must install silently and work immediately after install.

The portion of DevExpress keeping me from using PFC is the CharacterProperties object in the RichEditControl. Their support site already has a ticket that ends in "sorry, we can't make it work with PrivateFontCollection".

I've read from numerous sources and keep finding that ClickOnce cannot use a font right away when it installs it. I'm using P/Invoke to install the fonts since PFC is unavailable to me. I created a completely separate console app that does this font install, and the font shows up in Word, but it does not show up in my ClickOnce application even though I opened it after Word. I can install the font manually through the normal Windows click methods and it shows up in both Word and ClickOnce.

I verified with System.Drawing.Font that it is unavailable to the entire application, not just a picky vendor control:

```
Font fontTester = new Font(fontName, 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
if (fontTester.Name == fontName)
```

The "Name" value changes to "Microsoft Sans-Serif", acting as though the font is unavailable.

How do I get the font to show up in ClickOnce without a reboot/logoff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The P/Invoke method in the console app isn't working and I haven't the time to figure out why, but using VBScript with Shell.Application does.

```
Const FONTS = &H14&

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(FONTS)
objFolder.CopyHere "\\server\Fonts\barcodefont.ttf"
```

I had actually started with this, but for whatever reason it didn't work, so I moved onto other methods, including the console app.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can install a font in the traditional way by putting it into the Windows directory - the ClickOnce sandbox will stop you doing this sort of thing.

But you can add a font dynamically using code, but only for the current user.

This [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.addfontfile.aspx) shows the method AddFontFile on the System.Drawing.Text namespace and there is further discussion about this issue [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/clickonce-deployment-include-font-t2893983.html) (ignore the person wrongly saying it is not possible)

EDIT: Looks like it may be your namespace. See [C# - Read & Preview Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187212/c-sharp-read-preview-font)

I would try to just list out the fonts somehow from your app to see whether they can be read at all.

Comment: You cannot - as I said, "I created a completely separate console app that does this font install". The problem is, even though it's been installed, ClickOnce apps don't recognize it. The System.Drawing.Text, as I also said, was a test to demonstrate that it wasn't just the control. It's the control I need to get it into, but I can't even get it into the ClickOnce sandbox at all.